# Representing hierarchy in a mobile app

Tags: user-interface, mobile

Normally to represent hierarchy of items (parent-child) we use a tree control.

But on mobile devices it may be inconvenient. I have hardly seen any app that shows tree controls. Is there any alternative UI design that can represent hierarchy?

Thanks.

Regards,
Gautam Jain

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind would be like a menu. You would see a list of items and every time you click on one, the list would be replaced by the child list. You could use a back button to move back up the levels. This would make it easy to navigate at the disadvantage of not being able to see the whole structure at one time.